MPI comm.size is always 1
My MPI comm.size is always 1. I ran the following python script (test_mpi.py) to check if MPI was working properly.
mpirun -np 4 python test_mpi.py
from mpi4py import MPI
import mpi4py

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD

print(f"Hello from {comm.rank} of {comm.size}")

My output is:
Hello from 0 of 1
Hello from 0 of 1
Hello from 0 of 1
Hello from 0 of 1
I also tested a similar script with a C script and got the same results, so I am pretty sure the problem has to do with MPI and not mpi4py.
Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?
Btw I am also running inside a pyenv so I'm not sure if that affects anything. I installed everything inside the environment and it doesn't work.
I am expecting the output to be:
Hello from 0 of 4
Hello from 1 of 4
Hello from 2 of 4
Hello from 3 of 4
when I run test_mpi.py

What OS do you use? MPICH in Ubuntu 24.04 is bricked. Even a C hello world will print you "rank 0/1" multiple times. So, before looking into the issues of mpi4py, I would suggest to test a C program first on your system.

That typically occurs when mpirun and libmpi.so (either linked to your C program, or used under the hood by mpi4py) do not match.
You can
python -c "from mpi4py import MPI; print(MPI.Get_library_version())"

in order to figure out which MPI library is used by mpi4py, and then
mpirun -V

in order to figure out which MPI implentation provides mpirun.
If they do not match, either re-install mpi4py or use the matching mpirun
