MPI_Comm_size always returns 1 again
Using mpich 4.2.0-5build3 on Ubuntu24.04 and testing with the cpi.c small program that calculates the value of PI.
mpiexec -host host1 -n 2 cpi
The output is
Process 0 of 1 is on host1
pi is approximately 3.1415926544231341, Error is 0.0000000008333410
wall clock time = 0.000049
Process 0 of 1 is on host1
pi is approximately 3.1415926544231341, Error is 0.0000000008333410
wall clock time = 0.000046
It is running as if each process is in a cluster of 1?
That means The MPI_Comm_size function is returning a value of 1.
I read this other thread about accidental mixing of shared libraries of different MPI installations but I did a
ldd on the cpi as well as on mpiexec to check the library dependencies. So I know what shared libraries that they are using.
whereis mpiexec is also showing the one that is being used.
Any other ideas why MPI_Comm_size is always returning 1?

according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78755724/mpi-comm-size-is-always-1 mpich on ubuntu 24.04 is busted. try using Open MPI or rebuilding MPICH by yourself.

@GillesGouaillardet Thank you for the suggestion! I have already built the lastest MPICH first but it has its own problems. That is why I reverted to using this earlier build. Maybe I will give openMPI a go.

There is an issue with MPICH and mpiexec/mpirun on Ubuntu 24.04.
It seems MPICH was only built with PMIx support but mpiexec (hydra) only provides a PMI server.
A workaround is to build from source and prrte (several dependencies are needed such as libpmix-dev and libevent-dev
$ wget https://github.com/openpmix/prrte/releases/download/v3.0.6/prrte-3.0.6.tar.bz2
$ tar xvfj prrte-3.0.6.tar.bz2
$ cd prrte-3.0.6
$ make
$ sudo make install

and then use prterun instead of mpiexec or mpirun
$ prterun -n 2 ./hello_c
Hello, world, I am 0 of 2, (MPICH Version:      4.2.0
Hello, world, I am 1 of 2, (MPICH Version:      4.2.0


ok another way to bypass the problem, I guess!
